# Detect address from UITextView and show it map on tap

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uitextview, detect, street-address

There is an option in UITextView properties to detect address from the the text view text. However I am not able to do that. The text view is not in editable mode.

Do you know how to detect address from text view?
Is there a format that the address must have to be detected from the text view?

Answer (score 0):

A [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) won't automatically detect if text entered in the control is an address or provide you with the data you need to map the address on a map.  It is simple a control to display arbitrary text data to the user:

> You typically use a text view to display multiple lines of text, such as when displaying the body of a large text document.

I am not familiar with any algorithms to detect an address from a block of text, but if you work that part out, you can use [geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) to translate from the address to the latitude/longitude value you need to display it on a map.

Comment: @aj If there is anything I can add to this answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is 3 years too late, but I was recently struggling with a similar problem (data detector for phone on mapview). I had datadetectors turned on, and had editable turned off -- but I found that if I added a "\n" to the end of the string, the detector suddenly started working.

Answer (score 0):

For future folks landing here from search results, check out [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector)

```
let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.address.rawValue)

if detector?.firstMatch(in: textView.text, options: [], range: NSRange(textView.text) != nil,
  let addressRange = Range(match.range, in: textView.text) {

  let address = textView.text[range]
  // do something with address
}
```

I'm not using it in the context of an editable text view, but you could easily try to detect address (or other data type) each time the text view is edited